# Digit wise modulo for calculating power function for very very large positive integers

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I am writing a code to calculate $P^Q$ where $P$, $Q$ are positive integers which can have number of digits up to $100000$.

I want the result as $r = P^Q \pmod{10^9+7}$, where $10^9+7$ is a prime number.

Example:

$$\begin{align}
P &= 34534985349875439875439875349875\\
Q &= 93475349759384754395743975349573495
\\\quad\\
r &= 735851262
\end{align}$$

I tried using the trick:

$$\begin{align}
P^Q \pmod{10^9+7} &= \underbrace{P \times P \times \ldots \times P}_{Q \text{ times}} \pmod{10^9+7} = \\
&= \Big(\underbrace{P \pmod{10^9+7} \times \ldots \times P \pmod{10^9+7}}_{Q \text{ times}}\Big) \pmod{10^9+7}
\end{align}$$

Since both $P$ and $Q$ are very large, I should store them in an array and do modulo digit by digit.

Is there any efficient way of doing this or some number theory algorithm which I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know Fermat's little theorem (this will enable you to reduce Q)? And repeated squaring can be a better way of computing powers (you can reduce modulo your prime at any stage)

Comment: Thanks @MarkBennet Fermat's little theoram did the trick.

Comment: [Relevant](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884944/raising-to-the-power-over-finite-fields/884958#884958)

Comment: @MJD this link is awesome! Thanks

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm copying my answer from [Raising to the power over finite fields ??](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884944/raising-to-the-power-over-finite-fields/884958#884958) because OP said in a comment that it was useful.

---

One common trick, which requires $O(\log_2 m)$ multiplications, is to use the following algorithm:

1. If $m$ is even, calculate $b=a^{m/2}$ and then use one additional multiplication to find $a^m = b^2$.
2. If $m$ is odd, calculate $b=a^{(m-1)/2}$ and then use two additional multiplications to find $a^m = ab^2$.

For example, to calculate $a^{1000}$, you calculate the following, using one multiplication each: $a^2, a^3, a^6, a^7, a^{14}, a^{15}, a^{30}, a^{31}, a^{62}, a^{124}, a^{125}, a^{250}, a^{500}, a^{1000}$, for a total of 14 multiplications. To calculate $a^{1000000}$ would require only about twice as many multiplications.

This is not optimal, but it is fast enough that people often don't bother with anything faster.